# Message Broker / System integration question

Tags: c#, .net, integration, messaging, nservicebus

Need a general recommendation...

I have four systems I need to integrate. 2 have a queue based xml message api and 2 have web service api's.   All interaction will be asynchronous.

Interaction is point to point to point

```
A => B
A <= B
```

Quite a bit of the interaction is conversational (long running)

```
A => B
     B => C
     B <= C
     B => D
          D => E
A <=========== E
```

Looking for some free (or nearly free) package or library that can help rather than do all this plumbing/infrastructure code from scratch.   Took a peek at NServiceBus, however, after limited reading does not seem to be an exact fit.

Anyone have a recommendation on using NServiceBus for something like this or other alternatives rather than re-inventing the wheel.

We are a .Net shop.

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the sagas in NServiceBus might be what you're looking for.

http://nservicebus.com/sagas.aspx

Can you give some more details on your business requirements?